# Is there any way to test the order of Lists / Collections with jUnitJupiter?

Tags: java, list, junit-jupiter

I'm using JunitJupiter for unit testing. Now I'm at a point where I don't know how to check the order of a list.

**Code:**

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Should be in ascending order")
void sortAscending() {
    List<List<AccountlinevaluesEntity>> finalList = monthlySuSa;
    for (List<AccountlinevaluesEntity> list : finalList) {
        list.sort(Comparator.comparing(AccountlinevaluesEntity::getAccountNumber));
        assert(list, ...........);

    }
}
```

I'm pretty new to unit testing, i searched a lot but I didn't figure out how to do it.

So, is there any way to do this with jUnitJupiter or are there other ways to do this?

Comment: This is a completely useless test. You're not testing anything, since the sorting is done inside your test method instead of a business method. So basically you're testing whether you wrote the test correctly (and whether `list.sort()` works, and we know it does).

Comment: Yeah, that's right. This method is called in another method. I assumed that I should check every single one of my methods when testing.

Comment: So I test then whether the output of my business method was sorted correctly? or is it unnecessary to test how the sorting is, because we know that it will be correct?

Comment: I would test the sorting if a flawed sort could result in loss of life or money. Otherwise it's just a formatting issue, and there are more important things to test. I suggest some theoretical tutorials about testing, to understand better a) what you need to test, b) what you **don't** need to test, and c) how to write code to be easily testable. Otherwise you'll be writing tests without really knowing if they're useful.

Comment: Okay, right. Thank´s :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
assertThat(list, Matchers.contains("your", "items", "in", "order")
```

From JavaDoc

> Creates a matcher for {@link Iterable}s that matches when a single pass over the
>   examined {@link Iterable} yields a series of items, each logically equal to the
>   corresponding item in the specified items.  For a positive match, the examined iterable
>   must be of the same length as the number of specified items.